# Special character in string variable in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, sh

```
PubkeyContent=$(cat $Pubkey)    
read -r -d '' SSH_SCRIPT <<EOM
    \$(grep ${PubkeyContent} ~/.ssh/authorized_keys")
EOM
```

I got the wrong result.

```
[Debug] SSH_SCRIPT = $(grep ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAzSb7WKnMsysGA8kuq5Ysp02Y75d5 sam ~/.ssh/authorized_keys")com
```

I want this result

```
 [Debug] SSH_SCRIPT = $(grep "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAzSb7WKnMsysGA8kuq5Ysp02Y75d5 sam@com" ~/.ssh/authorized_keys")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix would be to quote the `PubkeyContent` variable content inside the here-doc, i.e.

```
read -r -d '' SSH_SCRIPT <<EOM
    \$(grep "${PubkeyContent}" ~/.ssh/authorized_keys")
EOM
```

or if you are using bash/ksh/zsh shell it supports a way to automatically slurp in the file content using input re-direction `< file` and thereby avoiding the useless use of `cat`. You can apply that inside command substitution as

```
read -r -d '' SSH_SCRIPT <<EOM
    \$(grep "$(<"$Pubkey")" ~/.ssh/authorized_keys")
EOM
```

Comment: What do you mean? What are you getting instead?

Comment: I think i kew why it is not working ....  because the public key is created by windows...

Comment: @Samuel: You can fix the DOS endings from the key and try the logic above again